# lubridate, calculate years, return NA

Tags: r, date, lubridate

hello i have a problem calculation the age of some subject knowing the date of birth, i am using the the lubridate package, sample:

```
> head(df$hs_dob1c)
[1] 2002-01-30 2004-12-29 2005-09-15 2002-12-20 2005-07-28 1995-08-28
```

firstly i set:

```
df$hs_dob1c <- as.Date(df$hs_dob1c, format='%y-%m-%d')
```

then:

```
today <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), format="%y-%m-%d")
ref_date <- as.Date(df$hs_dob1c, format="%y-%m-%d")
```

the problem is when i set the reference because:

```
> head(df$hs_dob1c)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where you used `lubridate`, but try

```
df$hs_dob1c <- as.Date(df$hs_dob1c, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

instead of

```
df$hs_dob1c <- as.Date(df$hs_dob1c, format='%y-%m-%d')
```

`%y` indicates a 2-digit year, you have a 4-digit year which should be referred as `%Y`

Answer (score 0):

Until now you didn´t use `lubridate`, but it will work with base **R**, too:

```
hs_dob1c <- as.Date(
  c("2002-01-30", "2004-12-29", "2005-09-15", "2002-12-20", "2005-07-28" ,"1995-08-28"),
  format='%Y-%m-%d')

today <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), format="%Y-%m-%d")

difftime(today, hs_dob1c, units = "days")
# Time differences in days
# [1] 5269 4205 3945 4945 3994 7616
```

Your have to change `format='%y-%m-%d'` to `format='%Y-%m-%d'`

With `lubridate` it will work like this:

```
library("lubridate")
hs_dob1c <- ymd(
  c("2002-01-30", "2004-12-29", "2005-09-15", "2002-12-20", "2005-07-28" ,"1995-08-28"))

today <- ymd(Sys.Date())

difftime(today, hs_dob1c,units = "days")
# Time differences in days
# [1] 5269 4205 3945 4945 3994 7616
```